# To prove that a smooth function is constant with restrictions to its derivative of order n.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth function defined on $[-1,1]$,$\forall n\in \mathbb{N},f^{(n)}(0)=0,\exists C\geq0$,$\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\left \| f^{(n)}(x) \right \| \leq n!C^n$.Prove that $f(x)\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor's formula we have
$$
f(a)= \sum_{k = 0}^N \frac{f^{k}(0)a^k}{k!} + R_{N}
$$
with 
$$
|R_N | \leq \frac{\|f^{N+1}\|}{(N+1)!}a^{N+1}.
$$
Inserting what we know, we get
$$
|f(a)| = |0 + R_N| \leq \frac{\|f^{N+1}\|}{(N+1)!}a^{N+1} \leq
C^{N+1}a^{N+1}.
$$
Now for $|a \cdot C | < 1$, we get the desired result. Since $\frac{1}{C}$ is positive, we can do the same thing again, but Tayloring at $\frac{C}{2a}$ and $-\frac{C}{2a}$. Doing this often enough we get the desired result for the intervall $[-1,1]$.

Essentially, I have shown that the set $\{x \in [-1,1] \mid f (x)= 0\}$ is open. Since it is closed by continuity, we get the result since $[-1,1]$ is connected.

Comment: Well, I think you mean 1/C by referring to C/a, am I right?

Comment: @Y.Hu yes, you are right. Fixed it.